# Delete all fail2ban bans in Ubuntu Linux

Tags: fail2ban

How can I delete all fail2ban bans in Ubuntu?
I tried everything but I don't get it.

I just want to delete all bans - but I don't know any IP adresses.

Comment: The bans are typically done on IP addresses through your firewall, so you should look at the firewall rules.

Comment: yes i know. but i want to clear all bans without telling a ip adress

Comment: "_I tried everything_" no you didn't. What did you try?

Answer (score 59):

#### Updated answer

As of version 0.10.0 `fail2ban-client` features the `unban` command that can be used in two ways:

```
unban --all                              unbans all IP addresses (in all
                                         jails and database)
unban <IP> ... <IP>                      unbans <IP> (in all jails and
                                         database)
```

Moreover, the `restart <JAIL>`, `reload <JAIL>` and `reload` commands now also have the `--unban` option.

#### Old Answer

fail2ban uses `iptables` to block traffic. If you would want to see the IP addresses that are currently blocked, type

```
iptables -L -n
```

and look for the various chains named `fail2ban-something`, where `something` points to the fail2ban jail (for instance, `Chain f2b-sshd` refers to the jail `sshd`).
If you only want to remove the block for a single IP address `<IP>` for a given jail `<JAIL>`, fail2ban offers its own client:

```
fail2ban-client set <JAIL> unbanip <IP>
```

Alternatively you can use line numbers. First, list the `iptables` rules with line numbers:

```
iptables -L -n --line-numbers
```

Next you can use

```
iptables -D fail2ban-somejail <linenumber>
```

to remove a single line from the table. As far as I know there is no option to select a range of line numbers, so I guess you would have to wrap this command in a for loop:

```
for lin in {200..1}; do
   iptables -D fail2ban-somejail $lin
done
```

Here I made the number 200 up. Check your own output of the command with `--line-numbers` and note that the last line (with `RETURN`) should stay. See @roaima's comment below for the reasoning behind counting down.

Comment: You saved me. Thanks a lot. Please add a full command because I had to figure out that I need fail2ban-client in frond of your command. (Because I am a noob)

Answer (score 20):

The best way to unban all IPs, is to set the bantime to 1 second, then all the IP will be freed right away.

```
fail2ban-client set JailName bantime 1
```

After that you can set the proper ban time back.

It's better to let fail2ban to do the unban for you. Don't manually edit iptables yourself.

Comment: This is the only correct answer here. Fail2ban maintains its own ban database that must be cleared independently. Every answer talking about deleting iptables rules ignores that the moment fail2ban is started back up it will re-add the rules you just deleted back to iptables. Also, not every fail2ban configuration uses iptables to implement bans.

Comment: find all jails with `fail2ban-client status`

Comment: I just issued this command and am watching the number of IPs in my jail decrease toward zero as fail2ban processes the jail. It does not happen really really fast, but that's OK, there were over five thousand entries in the jail. Good answer!

Answer (score 8):

The [latest `fail2ban-client` (0.10)](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/0.11/man/fail2ban-client.1) has a `unban -all` command. Jails can also be individually "restarted", effectively clearing the bans.

If you have an older version, this trick might work for automatic temporary bans: delete the jail which contains the ban then restart fail2ban so that the (now empty) jail would be recreated.

```
$ fail2ban-client stop sshd
Jail stopped
$ systemctl restart fail2ban
```

Comment: -all or —all?  Or --all?

Answer (score 7):

1. Stopping the service will clean all rules added by fail2ban

   ```
   service fail2ban stop
   ```
2. If you do not have any other iptables rules, you can flush it

   ```
   iptables -F
   ```

Be careful: **this will erase any other rules in your iptables**.

Comment: Just stopping then starting again was sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

Save iptable config to file

```
$ iptables-save > iptables.conf
```

Edit it with any editor you like
Than load config back to iptables

```
$ iptables-restore < iptables.conf
```

Do not forget to store configuration inside iptables so it will be picked up on reboot

```
$ service iptables save
iptables: Saving firewall rules to /etc/sysconfig/iptables:[  OK  ]
```

Answer (score 3):

heres a simple oneliner to unban the whole fail2ban jail the proper way:

```
iptables -L f2b-recidive -n | grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' | grep -v 0.0.0.0 | xargs -n 1 fail2ban-client set recidive unbanip
```

NOTE: iptables command takes "f2b-" prefix before the jail name while "fail2ban-client" the real jail name

Comment: This is the best answer for fail2ban versions bellow 0.10. You can go further creating an alias in .bashrc like fail2ban-purge with one parameter to purge a whole jail. Just replace recidive word above with $1 and use alias as fail2ban-purge <JAIL_NAME>.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the way `fail2ban` works, there are only two possible solutions:

- Make a firewall configuration script that includes `fail2ban` jails and restart the firewall.
- Remove the firewall rules blocking the IPs that you wish to unban.

Answer (score 2):

This is the script I'm using to unban all IP addresses for a ssh jail (simply replace sshd occourence with the name of jail you need... e.g. mysqld-auth)

```
#!/bin/bash
j=$(iptables -L f2b-sshd | grep -c 'REJECT')
for ((i=1;i<=j;i++))
do
  fail2ban-client set sshd unbanip $(fail2ban-client status sshd | grep 'Banned IP list:' | cut -c23-)
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way to unban all IP addresses from all jails:

1. stop the fail2ban service.
2. delete the `fail2ban.sqlite3` database. In my case it's located at `/var/lib/fail2ban/`.
3. start the fail2ban service: fail2ban will create a new database file from scratch.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer imho. It performs the desired task flawlessly. I would, however, delete log file too, as I think fai2ban pulls from that too.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this script could help someone with a version < 0.10.0 like me :

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

for JAIL in $(fail2ban-client status | grep 'Jail list:' | awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t"} {print $2}' | sed 's/, / /g')
do
  for IP in $(fail2ban-client status ${JAIL} | grep 'Banned IP list:' | awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t"} {print $2}' | sed 's/ /\n/g')
  do
    fail2ban-client set ${JAIL} unbanip ${IP}
  done
done

unset JAIL IP

exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

For drops all jails, use this command

```
fail2ban-client stop
```

Comment: This also stops the `fail2ban` server.